# Can minimum or subsidies or tax cuts really work? Or will resultant inflation always counterbalance such initiatives?

Tags: inflation, taxation, minimum-wage

I was born at the tail end of Eisenhower era and what is clear is that the dollar does not buy what it used to and this inflation has been more or less the trend for many decades.

I have yet to hear of a program that sounds to me like it will work. Recently min wage was increased where I live and sure enough prices and rent went up and businesses also laid off people, reduced hours and continued to automate.

A pilot subsidy program will appear to work: if you take a small number (say 100 in a city of 100k) of poor people and give them 1000 bucks each month, it seems obvious that they will benefit because this money will not significant affect prices. Do that for 10k out of the 100k and prices will go up.

Maybe I am not understanding the situation which is why I ask but is it possible that any program that puts "artificially" more money into the hands of the poor will eventually be counterbalanced by inflation?

If inflation is always the result, what is the solution?